# can't read utf8 strings from MySQL DB by an odbc client

Tags: c++, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, odbc

I have a DB with utf8 default charset, and a table that contains strings with non-ascii characters. I can read the data correctly by the `mysql` client program and the `isql` odbc client program (see examples below). However, when I read the table in my C++ client using the [libodbc++](http://libodbcxx.sourceforge.net/) odbc wrapper, I get garbage.

Curiously, I've been using the default MySql settings until now, i.e. `latin1` charset, but the data actually contained utf8 strings. This way, I was getting utf8 ok. I changed the DB to utf8 so that I can use `utf8_bin` collation.

Since I use `set names utf8` in the client I expect no charset conversion to happen between client and server. Am I wrong?

Are you aware of charset problems with libodbc++?

**EDIT**: just tested this with a "pure" odbc client (disgusting...), works ok. Strange, since libodbc++ is just a wrapper for odbc, I'd expect it not to have such effect on the data. Anyway, the suspect is libodbc++ library.

```
mysql> show full columns from tbl_list_domains;
+-------+-----------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field | Type      | Collation | Null | Key | Default | Extra | Privileges                      | Comment |
+-------+-----------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| word  | char(100) | utf8_bin  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         | 
+-------+-----------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+


$ mysql -u mysql navajoLocal <<< "set names utf8; select * from tbl_list_domains order by word limit 30" > out
```

The file `out` comes out good:

```
word
aa
ab
ac
ad
ae
...etc.
```

Using `isql` odbc client:

```
echo -e "set names utf8 \n select * from tbl_list_domains order by word limit 30" |isql mysql3-test -v -b -x0x20 > out
```

still good.

however this:

```
int main()
{
 ConnectionPtr conn = ConnectionPtr( DriverManager::getConnection("Driver=mysql3;database=navajoLocal;server=localhost;user=mysql;option=3;socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock") );

 StatementPtr st = StatementPtr( conn->createStatement() );
 st->executeUpdate("set names utf8 collate utf8_bin");

 ResultSetPtr res = ResultSetPtr( st->executeQuery("select word from tbl_list_domains order by word limit 30") );

 string s;
 while (res->next()) {
  s = res->getString(1);
  cout << s << endl;
 }
}
```

gives out this:

```
a^@
a^@
a^@
a^@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, found the guilty - it's the `libodbc++` library, as the edit says. Going to write to the authors. The solution would be to replace it with the MySql C++ connector. They both are modeled after JDBC, so the change is not big. Hope I will not be changing the DB soon...

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know if your problem is the same as mine.
I was trying to obtain a search result from a utf8_bin DB, using PHP and MySQL DB, but utf8_bin is very strict when talking about similar characters (like e é ë). So, when a query is used without the proper utf8 characters and/or case it doesn't return results or at least the ones expected. So, my oracle Google showed in MySQL docs the sollution for me using **_utf8** (note the underline) and **collate utf8_unicode_ci** in the SELECTS's WHERE clause like that:

```
SELECT field1,field2,field3
FROM `table1`
WHERE `table`.`field2` LIKE _utf8 '%$q%' collate utf8_unicode_ci
```

Hope it solves your problem.
P.S.: Sorry about my English. It is not my first language.

Comment: thanks. yes, the `_utf8` is an *introducer* (as here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-literal.html). The downside of such approach is that the conversion is done during the query execution, consuming time. And don't worry about your English - it's not the native tongue for most of us :)